# How do I fix this problem in blender 3.2?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image: Glitch thing]

How do I fix the hair from like phasing?[image: Thing 2]

Comment: Are the normals of your model facing the correct direction? Not exactly sure what you mean by "phasing" but that looks like reversed normals to me.

Comment: Please use proper tags for your questions. The blender-internal-render-engine is for questions about the legacy render engine Blender Internal that was shipped with Blender 2.79 and earlier versions.